# git switch from one branch to another without carrying the changes in the current branch

Tags: git

I don't know if this is normal in Git but whenever I move from one branch to another, the changes in that current branch that I am in is carried on to the branch where I switch on.

For example, I have the `master` branch and then I created a `branch2`. I added some files to `branch2` and committed all of it. Then I create a new branch and switch to it using `git checkout -b branch3`. The files that I have added on `branch2` is now on `branch3` as well. But what I want is only the things that I have on my `master` branch.

The only solution that I found so far is to switch to the `master` branch first and then use `git checkout -b branch3` so that I won't get the changes from `branch2`.

Is there a shortcut to this? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a shortcut to switching to the master branch before you make `branch3`, you can use `git checkout -b branch3 master`.

This second argument is called the "start point", and it defines the branch that the new branch should be based on.

For more details here about the `git branch` command, see the [git-scm docs for git branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).